# Duda Try catch anidado

Tags: c#

mi duda es si yo tengo un try catch dentro de otro cual prioriza, un ejemplo:

```
        try
        {            

            try
            {
                ... //aqui se da un error
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Log.Error(e.Message, e);
            return -1;
        }
```

En casos como este donde en el catch interno no haya nada salta al ultimo catch o vuelve en el catch interno?

Muchas Gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Siempre irá al catch del try anidado, en tu caso iria al interno.

Comment: Estará en el `catch`interno, ahi debes usar la excepcion de igual manera, o en su caso en donde más convenga un `finally`.

Comment: Si quieres que después de entrar en el `catch` interno llegué al principal tendrás que forzar una excepción, para ello tendrías que definir en el `catch` interno un `throw`. Podrías revisar: [Excepciones y control de excepciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/), en ella encontrarás el tema de `Crear y producir excepciones`.

Comment: Entonces si no hay nada en el catch interno como en el ejemplo busca el siguiente catch o directamente no maneja la excepcion? porque por logeos mi programa crasheo en ese metodo y todo tiene try catch salvo ese catch vacio